# Formula that return the date when the checkbox was selected

Tags: formula, formula-field, field-update

I am trying to make a formula which will return the date when the checkbox was clicked. This is what I got now and it's not working since it gives the value for all fields as same date.

```
if(Call_Attempts__c = True , NOW(), NULL )
```

I know that the code NOW() gives all values for current date for all fields and I need a return date for last modified specific field.

Thanks,

Darko

Comment: All that formula is doing is displaying the current date when `Call_Attempts__c ` is true. What you are trying to do is not possible with a formula. You would need to create a new date field (e.g. `Call_Attempts_Date__c ` ) and set it in a trigger when `Call_Attempts__c ` is checked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of a formula, create a new Date or Datetime field, and update it to NOW() via a Workflow Field Update or via a trigger, whenever you detect that the Checkbox value has been changed from False to True.